# jTable in Django

Tags: jquery, django, html-table, jquery-jtable

Can we use use jTables in Django... I searched a lot but didn't found any relevant material..
Also if its possible, in what format should I pass my data to html page.. (I mean like - list of lists)??

I want to perform some function on click of the some row on the run time, how to achieve that?? In the tutorials available [here](http://www.jtable.org/Home/Documents) I don't know what is **Repository** and how its being used, what's its structure.

Is there something equivalent to jTable for Django??

**Work done till now**
I created a function that is fetching data from DB in list-of-lists format

Please help, I am new buddy to Django

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found something that is similar to jTables [here](http://django-tables2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/).. This has most of the features what I wanted